# If more than one gamepad button pressed via UWP JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, uwp, gamepad

According to Microsoft docs, `GamepadReading.buttons`, It's combination of buttons values...

Inside game loop via `window.requestAnimationFrame` (Or `window.setInterval`), I'm trying to implement way to check for pressing multiple gamepad buttons...

Here is the implementation, Although i used strings instead...

```js
function gamepadButtonPressed(gamepad_index, button) {
    var gamepad_state = window.Windows.Gaming.Input.Gamepad.gamepads[gamepad_index].getCurrentReading();
    if (button === "leftTrigger" || button === "rightTrigger") return (gamepad_state[button] >= 0.1);
    else return (gamepad_state.buttons === window.Windows.Gaming.Input.GamepadButtons[button]); 
}
```

The problem i have is, The gamepad reading state changes each time, But i want way to not let this only detect one button, But also make it able to do multiple buttons, Instead of being forced to be one button...

If someone can help i'll be very grateful!

Comment: Still not very clear about what you want to do? Do you mean you want to detect different button pressed on multi gamepads?

Comment: Yep, multiple buttons...
But seems difficult!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with bitwise `&` operator.

```js
function gamepadButtonPressed(gamepad_index, button) {
    var gamepad_state = window.Windows.Gaming.Input.Gamepad.gamepads[gamepad_index].getCurrentReading();
    if (button === "leftTrigger" || button === "rightTrigger") return (gamepad_state[button] >= 0.1);
    else return (gamepad_state.buttons & window.Windows.Gaming.Input.GamepadButtons[button] != 0); 
}
```